# PHP Fatal error: Class 'OAuth'

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, pecl

I searched the site for hours looking for answer and nothing helped me. I’ve installed PHP/Apache2/PECL/OAuth and edited php.ini for `extension=oauth`. I get this error everything I type "php example.php" I'd set the token and everything required in example.php

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found in /home/twitter/TwitterAutoReply.php on line 22

My php files is example.php and TwitterAutoReply.php

https://raw.github.com/gist/820281/303a61ee9b324070e803e51806552e64fccfdd4c/example.php 
and https://gist.github.com/raw/820281/6bf1b6d78dd05daef319ce84a88eedf139a44b5a/TwitterAutoReply.php

Comment: Judging from the error you are failing to run the `class OAuth` which is programming related (PHP file) not an apache extension.

Comment: Surprisingly, it actually is an extension. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.oauth.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error, you're not importing the oauth package in you php.ini file.
For ubuntu, you need to install oauth:

```
sudo pecl install oauth
```

Then include the oauth package in your php.ini. If you don't know where the file is, you can use:

```
sudo find / -name "oauth.so"
```

Using the path to the extension add the following to your php.ini:

```
extension=/path/to/oauth/package/oauth.so
```

Restart apache and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that the extension is actually loaded. To verify that it is, simply ask PHP something about the OAuth extension, in a command like:

```
php --re oauth
```

If this doesn't show information about the module but instead gives an error, you'll know that it's not loaded. Additionally you could simply list all loaded modules with `php -m`.

Try manually loading the extension by using `-z oauth` in your command. Example: `php -z oauth example.php`. If that works, you didn't edit your php.ini correctly.

Comment: root@q8edit /oauth-1.2.2 # php -z oauth /home/twitter/example.php 
Failed loading oauth:  oauth: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found in /home/twitter/TwitterAutoReply.php on line 22

Comment: And there's your answer - it can't even find the file. Make sure you put it in the right directory. My PHP.ini had to have `extension_dir=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/` before it worked - that path is where PECL placed its stuff in my case, but that may be different for you.

Comment: make sure to restart the httpd service if the above command shows OAuth installed but you are still having trouble, that was the fix in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The command `php --re oauth` solved my issue.

Seems there was some miss coding with `php.ini`. the command gives me error, I removed those lines and re-install oauth, restarted httpd and it loads that extension successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on oauth client and in the situation without an ability to change the environment (add php-oauth extension). the following solution worked out for me:

1) install Zend OAuth

`composer require zendframework/zendoauth`

2)using the following in PHP code:

`$hmac = new \ZendOAuth\Signature\Hmac($consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret, 'SHA1');
return $hmac->sign($data, $method, $url);`

instead of

`$oauth = new OAuth(...
$oauth->generateSignature(...`