# PHP fatal error: class oauth still not found

Tags: php, oauth, pecl

I follow the solution of [PHP Fatal error: Class 'OAuth'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370362/php-fatal-error-class-oauth), but still get the same error.

installation

```
$ sudo pecl install oauth
```

then add the following line to the end of /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/oauth.so
```

Both "php -m" and "php --re oauth" return something. But "php -z" does not work and no OAuth from phpinfo() either.

```
$ php -z oauth /var/www/html/oauth.php
Failed loading oauth:  oauth: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /var/www/html/oauth.php
```

One thing to note, I am running PHP on apache2 as docker container behind nginx proxy. Would that be a problem? I verify PHP via phpinfo(), which is working fine.

The system is Ubuntu 16.04, also.

```
$ pecl list
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package Version State
oauth   2.0.2   stable
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` only exists when run php as web server or cgi mode. So if you run in cli mode, the `$_SERVER` does not contain `HTTP_HOST` index. Try to access a not exiting index will throw a `notice`.

Otherwise, if a request is over `ip` rather than `host`, this index would not exist.